# Как сделать так чтобы элементы были в одну строку

Tags: html, css

Я написал стандартный код HTML:

```css
#test {
  transition: 1s all;
  border: 4px solid rgb(44, 49, 54);
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 1825px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

#test:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

body {
  background: url(images/1.jpg) black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js">
</script>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Это гаишник</h1>
    <h1 id="test">|<br/>|<br/>|</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Вот такой сайт
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но мне надо чтобы рамка и текст находились на одном уровне
А именно так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример на flexbox

```css
.dflex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.test {
  transition: 1s all;
  border: 4px solid rgb(44, 49, 54);
  padding: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.test:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

body {
  background: url(images/1.jpg) black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js">
</script>

<body>
  <div class="dflex">
    <h1>Это гаишник</h1>
    <div class="test">|<br/>|<br/>|</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Не используйте на странице более одного h1 SEO этого крайне не любит

Comment: Semenov Спасибо за совет возьму на заметку